# After restore, Photos is uploading items

Tags: icloud, photos, restore

Last week I backed up my phone on my local iTunes. I switched to "Optimise iPhone Storage" for Photos to keep the size of the backup small.

After I restored the phone, Photos says "Uploading 30,000 Items". There are no local photos, so I wonder what is uploaded and if this is messing up my iCloud Photo Library?

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same issue because I restored from an iTunes backup which had all my pictures inside (I bought the 256GB to have all my photos on the device). 
Doing so first created a 40GB extra iCloud backup for my iPhone from nowhere then added about 15GB of data to my iCloud Drive folder. No idea what is in there.
Have been in touch with two Apple advisors in these days:

1. the first told me that this is normal
2. the second one made me perform a turn off / on of the iCloud Photo library (which didn't help), then a log out/in of the iCloud account (which didn't help).

They said to wait 72hrs! I wonder how this is considered acceptable! 
I hope those two steps they made me do can help you.